# How do I effectively run very large computations in ReactJs and NodeJs without degrading performance?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have to calculate thousands of computations on the fly in a Reactjs with Node.js endpoints and I am concerned about heading the wrong direction and degrading performance. For example the client sells shoes. For each brand and model of shoe we need to calculate how many were sold in all stores and compare it to how many were sold in this store (during the selected time period). That could mean that we need to calculate hundreds of brands, multiple of models for each brand across the store every day for a selected period of time, while doing same for each of the other stores to get a baseline to compare to.Effectively, what did all the other stores do during this period for this and all other models of this brand and what did we do (are we better or worse).

The math itself is not the issue, its the computation time that concerns me. The client can also select the date range or the store range on the fly and then again all need to be recalculated (what did we do on this model of this brand during this new period against this new subset of stores).

Is it possible to get some guidance on: do I do this type of calculation in Node.js or Reactjs? Or do I go for some other back-end technology and process this in memory for example. I am needing to understand a route to take to research.

Appreciate it.

Comment: Depends on how the information is stored. Typically such tasks are done by the DBMS.

Comment: Everything you mention does not sound like very large computations to me. Doing this for each query would be slow in other languages such as PHP or Ruby and my usual fix for this is to rewrite this in node.js or go. Once you're in the range of hundreds of thousands of elements of data then it becomes fairly big - in any language.

Comment: Thanks, I worry this is going to get fairy significant from a data perspective. There will be huge amounts of brands and models multiplied for each day (and the selected time period could be months) and then doing the same across hundreds of stores to get a comparison base. This will allow you to calculate how you have compared. I worry of going down a route that as you expand will just fall over or destroy user experience.